# Order for searching multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, search, select, query-performance

I have 5 tables table1 - table5 with increasing number of rows.

```
Table1 have about 1000 rows
Table2 - 10,000 rows 
Table3 - 50,000 rows
Table4 - 100,000 rows
and Table5 - 10,00,000 rows
```

I want to select the row containing the account_number which could be in any of the tables.

I am confused about best way to search for account_number Table1, Table2,...Table5?
or Table5, Table4, ... Table1.
Please suggest.

Note: The tables are expected to increase with time by up to 40 orders of magnitude. That means Table5 is expected to hold about `4,00,00,000` rows an year from now so I am being careful from start and want to search no more than required.

Comment: Is the row your are looking for only in any one of the tables or could it me in more than one table?

Comment: @LalitKumarB the desired row could only be in a single table or it couldn't exist at all.

Comment: Just a remark: The table design looks a bit strange. If an account number can only reside in one of the tables at a time, why do I have to scan the tables rather than knowing where it resides in? Usually such would be modelled either with only one table holding all rows plus a status column or with a master table where the account number is primary key giving you the link to the table in question. (The design decision usually depends on how similar the tables are.)

Comment: @Gurpreet I have added a demonstration with `9,999,999 rows`. And I get the row in **less than a second**.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The Electricity Utility company I work for have multiple categories of users and separate tables for each i.e. something like heavy industry (table1 - least number of rows), medium industry (table2), light ind. (table3), commercial/shops etc (table4) and finally general consumers (table5 - max num of rows). When a consumer search for his/her bill we don't want to ask him/her about category we only get account number and hence have to search all the tables for finding the bill of the consumer.

Comment: The first question is: Why is this separate tables instead of one table with a type column saying whether the account is on 'heavy industry', 'medium industry' etc. and the account number being the primary key? This would be the straight forward design and usually easiest to handle with SQL. [to be continued...]

Comment: Well, maybe the tables are very different from each other, having only few columns in common. Then one would still expect one table for the account. And this table would either have a column type ('heavy industry', 'medium industry', etc.) or even IDs (id_heavy, id_medium) with a constraint assuring that only one at a time is not null.

Comment: The tables are very different from each other, even in the number of columns. We aren't using a mapping table containing info about which account number is in which table because its would be difficult to keep up to date. These tables will also have heavy insertion because of addition of new bills for each consumer every month.

Answer (score 2):

A table having *merely a million rows*, with required **index** and **statistics gathered up to date** shouldn't be an issue.

To gather the **table statistics**,

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME');
```

The other tables are much smaller compared to the biggest one. To scan a table with **1000 rows** would take some **milli-seconds**? Ok, a second or two? It is fine.

Few things definitely depend on what kind of environment it is. OLAP or OLTP. However, we are talking about at most 1 million rows. It should be quick enough.

Add an **index** to the **account number column** since you would use it in the **filter predicate**, and check the **explain plan** before executing the query.

If you know that the probability of getting the row in table 5 is as high as 95%, then start with table 5. If you find the row, pretty good and lucky. Else, you are left with much smaller tables.

Let's look at a practical example :

### **Setup a big table with 9,999,999 rows**

```
SQL> create table big_table
  2  as
  3  select rownum id,
  4                 OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, SUBOBJECT_NAME,
  5                 OBJECT_ID, DATA_OBJECT_ID,
  6                 OBJECT_TYPE, CREATED, LAST_DDL_TIME,
  7                 TIMESTAMP, STATUS, TEMPORARY,
  8                 GENERATED, SECONDARY
  9    from all_objects a
 10   where 1=0
 11  /

Table created.

SQL> alter table big_table nologging;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2      l_cnt number;
  3      l_rows number := 9999999;
  4  begin
  5      insert /*+ append */
  6      into big_table
  7      select rownum,
  8                 OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, SUBOBJECT_NAME,
  9                 OBJECT_ID, DATA_OBJECT_ID,
 10                 OBJECT_TYPE, CREATED, LAST_DDL_TIME,
 11                 TIMESTAMP, STATUS, TEMPORARY,
 12                 GENERATED, SECONDARY
 13        FROM all_objects A
 14       where rownum <= 9999999;
 15
 16      l_cnt := sql%rowcount;
 17
 18      commit;
 19
 20      while (l_cnt < l_rows)
 21      loop
 22          insert /*+ APPEND */ into big_table
 23          select rownum+l_cnt,
 24                 OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, SUBOBJECT_NAME,
 25                 OBJECT_ID, DATA_OBJECT_ID,
 26                 OBJECT_TYPE, CREATED, LAST_DDL_TIME,
 27                 TIMESTAMP, STATUS, TEMPORARY,
 28                 GENERATED, SECONDARY
 29            from big_table
 30           where rownum <= l_rows-l_cnt;
 31          l_cnt := l_cnt + sql%rowcount;
 32          commit;
 33      end loop;
 34  end;
 35  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Now I have a **big table** with **9,999,999 rows**:

```
SQL> SET TIME ON timing ON
11:36:54 SQL>
11:36:54 SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM big_table;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   9999999

Elapsed: 00:00:01.82
11:36:56 SQL>
```

### **Create the required index**

```
11:36:56 SQL> CREATE INDEX big_indx ON big_table(object_name);

Index created.

Elapsed: 00:00:31.31
11:37:27 SQL>
```

I created an **index** on `object_name` which took some `30 seconds`. To be on safer side, I have **gathered the statistics** on the newly created table:

```
11:37:27 SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('LALIT', 'BIG_TABLE');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:15.92
11:37:43 SQL>
```

### Let's check the **EXPLAIN PLAN**:

```
11:40:16 SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
11:40:22   2  SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME FROM big_table WHERE OBJECT_NAME='BIG_TABLE';

Explained.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
11:40:26 SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1170786741

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |           |    23 |   713 |   128   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE                         |           |    23 |   713 |   128   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| BIG_TABLE |   194 |  6014 |   128   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | BIG_INDX  |   194 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("OBJECT_NAME"='BIG_TABLE')

15 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.06
11:40:37 SQL>
```

So, explain plan looks good. I see an **index range scan**. So, my index is being used, which is a good news.

Now, let's see how much time it takes to search for the row I am interested in:

```
11:42:41 SQL> SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME FROM big_table WHERE OBJECT_NAME='BIG_TABLE';

OWNER OBJECT_NAME
----- ---------------
LALIT BIG_TABLE

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
11:43:05 SQL>
```

What do we see? It took even **less than a second**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer contains so many new things for me.

Comment: @Gurpreet You're welcome. You have marked an incorrect answer as answered. It is not an Oracle syntax in the accepted answer. You should mark only a correct answer as answered. Folks looking for a similar problem will never get helped.

Comment: I didn't checked the syntax I just found the idea good. It  allows me to exit the query as soon as the record is found.

Comment: You can't do that in Oracle in pure SQL. `IF EXISTS` is not supported in Oracle. Follow my suggestions as demonstrated in the answer. Performance will be much better than your expectations.

Comment: Adding an index is a good idea but the tables will undergo heavy insertion also. The index will make the insertion slow. I am talking about insertion of hundreds of records in a loop by reading from cvs files, from multiple locations, daily.

Comment: You need to think about the schema design. If this is a staging table, then you would obviously not use a staging table in your application code to fetch the data frequently. I assume this to be a one-time activity and not done through application. So, depends on lot of factors whether you need an index or not. I demonstrated an example to show how index would be helpful in your case, and especially the fact that a million rows table is not that huge to worry about performance to just fetch a row based on a simple filter predicate.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
Select * From table1 Where account_number = 'myAccountNumber'
Union
Select * From table2 Where account_number = 'myAccountNumber'
Union 
Select * From table3 Where account_number = 'myAccountNumber' 
Union
Select * From table4 Where account_number = 'myAccountNumber' 
Union
Select * From table5 Where account_number = 'myAccountNumber'
```

The results from each query are merged together.  This could then be ordered depending on preference.

Comment: Wouldn't this be costly? I am searching all the tables all the time so I will lose the benefit in case row is found in very first table.

Comment: Both Union options stated here will work well.  If you have good indexing on your tables, there should be no performance hit.  You may want to add a literal field 'TableX' as tableName in the unions if you want to know which table the account number was in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select temp.col1, temp.col2, temp.col3,.....
from
(   select col1, col2, col3,.... from table1
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3,.... from table2
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3,.... from table3
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3,.... from table4
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3,.... from table5
 ) temp
 where colX = 'account number';
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be costly? I am searching all the tables all the time so I will lose the benefit in case row is found in very first table.

Answer (score 1):

The row counts you are looking at small, and there should be no problem with a union.  For interest though, if you wanted to check one table first, and then not query further, a stored procedure like this will work.

```
DECLARE @AccountNum AS TABLE (account_number VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @AccountNum(account_number ) SELECT account_number FROM Table1

IF EXISTS (SELECT account_number FROM @AccountNum)
BEGIN
 SELECT account_number FROM @AccountNum
 RETURN
END

INSERT INTO @AccountNum(account_number ) SELECT account_number FROM Table2

IF EXISTS (SELECT account_number FROM @AccountNum)
BEGIN
 SELECT account_number FROM @AccountNum
 RETURN
END
```

I think the union option is still the best fit.

Comment: The tables are expected to increase with time by upto 40 orders of magnitude. That means Table5 is expected to hold about 4,00,00,000 rows an year from now so I am being careful from start and want to search no more than required.

Comment: I can vouch that with 40,000,000 rows, the search wouldn't take more than few seconds.

Comment: By the way, your question was regarding Oracle. And this answer uses SQL Server syntax.

Comment: That is invalid syntax for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can start from table1 and go till table5 as for the simple reason that table1 has least number of records so the Oracle engine has to search on less number of records and if the record is found in table1 then it does not have to go to table2 and like wise.

You can try like this:

```
select * 
from table5
where account_number = 'myAccountNumber'
UNION ALL

select * 
from table4 e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT id FROM table5 ee WHERE ee.id = e.id)
and e.account_number = 'myAccountNumber'
UNION ALL

select * 
from table3 e
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT id FROM table5 ee WHERE ee.id = e.id)
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT id FROM table4 ee WHERE ee.id = e.id)
and e.account_number = 'myAccountNumber'
UNION ALL

select * from table2 e
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT id FROM table5 ee WHERE ee.id = e.id)
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT id FROM table4 ee WHERE ee.id = e.id)
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT id FROM table3 ee WHERE ee.id = e.id)
    and e.account_number = 'myAccountNumber'
```

Comment: I am inclined for the same but then I think about probabilities. Account_number is expected to be found in Table5 around 95% of time. So shouldn't we first target the table with highest probability of getting the hit?

Comment: @Gurpreet:- You didnt mention about this in your question. However if you are sure that 95% of the time your result is in table5 then yes you can first search in table5 and then with the table with less probability and so one!

Comment: @Gurpreet:-I have updated my answer with the query which you can use to check the result.!